# Bootstrap 3 page width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Unfortunately I'm having to use bootstrap

http://www.ttmt.org.uk/bootstrap/

Simple question how is it / is it possible to have a page width that isn't 1140px.

If Bootstrap uses 12 columns I'm assuming they have have a set width and margin.

How is it possible to have a page width that isn't 1140px.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use
    `<div class="container-fluid">`
so that it will fill the full width of the element.

is this what your asking?

Comment: If I use container-fulid the container is 100% width. I want a container that is 1500px in width. The container class has a width of 1140px. If I style the container class with a width of 1500px it starts at that width but is no longer responsive.

Comment: i changed .container to 1500px, was still responsive for me.`.container {
width: 1500px;
}`

Comment: @ttmt, you should mention that spec in your question. All you've said is what you don't want it to be...

Answer (score 0):

Just add a media query that sets the .container width to 1500px when the screen size is =< than 1500px.

```
@media (min-width: 1500px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1500px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example link seems to be dead, so you should post some code or a bootply... That being said, here are some answers:

> *If Bootstrap uses 12 columns I'm assuming they have have a set width*
>   *and margin.*

Not in pixels... they have a width that are a set % of total width, depending on their # (eg col-xs-6 is 50% of the widhth, because 6 is 50% of 12).

> *How is it possible to have a page width that isn't 1140px?*

Change the container width when appropriate with a media query like so:

```
@media (min-width: 1500px) {
  .container {
    width: 1500px;
  }
}
```